# MVC in php, a convention that I came up 

Tags: php, frameworks

Basically, I started working in a more mvc manner where I have my html, objects, executing code, seperated into views,module, code.

So for example, if I want to create a registration form, I create a folder called "Registration" and put three files:

---

**Registration** 
--- Views (contains html table and form) 
--- Module (contains a class that validates output and inserts the new user). 
--- Controller (executes the class in the module file).

---

My question is the way I work called MVC?
Another question how time saving are the existing frameworks in php eg. ruby on rails, zend framework..
I am a bit new to php and I am not sure if it is worth swaping to one of them 1?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you work is MVC but i think it would save you a lot of time, switching to a framework that is designed from scratch with MVC in mind. The learning curve is always a bit strange...a bit tough at start but time saving for as long as you will be a developer. If it is a big project i would suggest Symfony2 with Doctrine2.0

Comment: how much time do I really lose by not using any framework at all?!?

Comment: this depends on your experience and since you are new to this, you are going to make a lot of "mistakes" and wrong choices that will be avoided by using a framework. At least before you decide take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: I can see what you mean. But I think I need to program in raw php before passing to a framework. I see that it simplifies things. Thanks for the link

Comment: Yes, of course you should start from raw php. Just have in mind to quickly move to the next level in order to improve your skills.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite, but close.

MVC stands for *Model-View-Controller*.

- **Models** contain domain logic. They represent pieces of data, and can handle persistence (e.g. storing/fetching data in a database.)
- **Views** contain presentation (and presentation logic). Some people like to separate the two, creating a **View Controller** that contains the presentation logic and keep the view simple. Regardless, views are where your HTML goes.
- **Controllers** contain application logic. They typically tie together models and views, and should be fairly lightweight. Most of the heavy lifting is done by the model.

As far as frameworks are concerned, do your research. I would not recommend Zend Framework for beginners, but that's just me. Ruby on Rails is not PHP.

Frameworks are nice in that they help "force" you to be organized, but are not a do-all-end-all solution. Sometimes they get in the way, sometimes they make things really easy.

Just to get you started in the a framework mindset, check out [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). While I personally have not used it in a long time, it is a good framework for beginners to jump in to. The docs are great and community is decent.

Comment: if ruby on rails is not php..what is it?!? and could I just program without any official framework? could I make my own framework.. I mean I can make my own classes like roles, registration, pager, login. and copy them from one project/website to another? .. zendframework involves some convoluted way to establish roles, which I could do in 5 mins with inheritance

Comment: how much time do I really lose by not using any framework at all?!?

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a framework for Ruby. Ruby != PHP.  *"Can I program without any official framework?"* Yes, I do it quite often.  *"Could I make my own framework?"* Yes. Are you willing to maintain it and bugfix it?  Keep in mind, **most** of the popular frameworks use common best-practices (although some diverge) that you can learn from better than if you make your own right away.

Comment: *"zendframework involves some convoluted way to establish roles, which I could do in 5 mins with inheritance"* I did say I **don't** recommend Zend Framework for beginners. Zend abstracts everything in to components, and you have to figure out how to tie them all together. While that makes it extremely flexible, it may be "extremely difficult" to figure it all out.

Comment: *"how much time do I really lose by not using any framework at all?!?"* Could be minutes, could be hours, could be days -- weeks -- months. Depends entirely on the scale and purpose of the application being developed.

Comment: Thanks I will stick to pure php..and may be after one year of programming I will shift to zend framework.. it seems to be too rigid . .. and the point of inheritance,,i think you misunderstood me a bit.. I mean the zends way of making roles, is too rigid.. what If i wanted to add more functionality to the moderator that doesnt exist in the framework

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into creating your model view and controller through the powershell by typing commands like "zf create controller controller_a" or "zf create project project1" rather than typing out all of that nonsense.

You'll have to configure an environment variable to run the commands in powershell.

I find frameworks very powerful. It's ultimately up to you to decide what you are comfortable with.

Comment: I hate typing commands. I hate shell.. The way I type things make it easy for me to debug the whole thing

Comment: These commands just generate the files for you ensuring you utilize each component in the right directory with the right functions prepared for you. You still write code in the same files the same way you were. Nor does it change the way you debug your application.

Comment: zf create project project1 is 26 characters long. The code it generates is closer to 400 characters long.